# I am new to javascript, and I am trying to make a html program to calculate dog age

Tags: javascript

No matter what I do, the underneath code only prints out the else and it comes out as undefined. What am I doing wrong?

```js
function calcDogAge() {
  var dogAge = document.getElementsByName("dogAge").valueOf.isNumber;

  if (dogAge >= 2) {
    var old = (dogAge * 4) + 13;
    document.getElementsById("dogogo").innerHTML = "Your dog is " + old + "years old.";
  } else if (dogAge < 2) {
    var young = dogAge * 10.5;
    document.getElementById("dogogo").innerHTML = "Your dog is " + young + "years old.";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("dogogo").innerHTML = dogAge;
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" class="dogAge" name="dogAge"/>
<button onclick = "calcDogAge()">Find dog age now</button>
<p id="dogogo"></p>
```

Comment: Are you sure that `document.getElementsByName("dogAge")` is returning what you're expecting it to?

Comment: `.valueOf.isNumber` should do what exactly? Have you ever used `console.log()`

Comment: `document.getElementsByName('')` returns a `nodelist` which does not have a `valueOf.` This also makes `.isNumber` an invalid statement. Do you have errors in your debug console?

Comment: Unrelated: if `dogAge` isn't `>= 2` the only other option is `< 2`.

Comment: @Sierra Kosel Open up your console (F12 in most browsers) and read the error messages. There are a lot of syntax errors in this code that will become clear.

Comment: What does >= 2 does even mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the fixes in comments:

```js
const btnCalc = document.getElementById("btnCalc"), // cache your elements
      dogAge  = document.getElementById("dogAge"),  // use the right method for DOM query
      dogogo  = document.getElementById("dogogo");

function calcDogAge() {
  const n = parseInt(dogAge.value, 10); // input gives always a string, so use parseInt
  if (n >= 2) {
    var old = n * 4 + 13;
    dogogo.innerHTML = "Your dog is " + old + " years old.";
  } else if (n < 2) {
    var young = n * 10.5;
    dogogo.innerHTML = "Your dog is " + young + " years old.";
  } else {
    dogogo.innerHTML = n;
  }
}

// Don't use inline JavaScript, instead use listeners inside your JS code
btnCalc.addEventListener('click', calcDogAge);
```

```html
<input id="dogAge" type="number">
<button id="btnCalc">Find dog age now</button>
<p id="dogogo"></p>
```

or a slight modification:

```js
const EL = (sel) => document.querySelector(sel),
      EL_res = EL('#res'),
      EL_age = EL('#age');

const calcAge = () => {
  const n = parseInt(EL_age.value, 10); 
  let y = 0;
  if (n >= 2)  y = n * 4 + 13;
  else if (n < 2) y = n * 10.5;
  EL_res.innerHTML = `Your dog is ${y} years old.`;
};

EL("#btn").addEventListener('click', calcAge);
```

```html
<input id="age" type="number">
<button id="btn">Find dog age now</button>
<p id="res"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `var dogAge = document.getElementsByName("dogAge").valueOf.isNumber;`

by

`var dogAge = document.getElementsByName("dogAge")[0].value;`

as getElementsByName returns a list of all nodes with the given name.
Also, you have a misspelled getElementByID in the first if condition

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it was that close.

Comment: @sierra Please accept the answer if it meets your requirement.